# Notification whenever a new entry is made to the firebase storage

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web

So, I am working on a website and i want to implement something. I am using firebase to send normal html form stuff to the firebase database, One page has a form which also has a an attachment option where the user has to put in his resume, I am able to send the pdf file to the firebase storage but i want that the owner of the site/admin is notified whenever somebody new registers is there any way i can implement this by either sending the owner an email that somebody applied/registered if yes please guide me or some resources to do the same and also if this can be done by firebase itself or i have to do something with the third party.

Comment: Your form is hosted somewhere, so you should have a backend available. After successful form submission, use a 2nd request to have the backend send out the email.

Comment: My Form is not yet hosted, for backend all i have is firebase and i am fairly new to it, so basically send out it from the code? Using the SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a front-end app only (e.g. a React app or similar), and don't have a back-end, I would suggest you use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) for this.

You can make a Cloud Function that runs every time a file is added to Firebase Storage. There's an example of such a function in the examples repository [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/thumbnails). This particular function generates a thumbnail for images, but you can look through it and get an idea of how the functions work with Storage triggers.

You can then look at another example which sends emails, like [this one](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users) and hopefully you will have a pretty good idea of what you need to do.

More info on Cloud Functions triggered by Firebase Storage can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events).

Comment: Thank you so much! Also It's a basic website so I am not really using any framework for it that's why decided to go for Firebase, i did find an answer where they also suggested Firebase Cloud Functions, thank you so much for the resources!